# PHP - Generate an 8 character hash from an integer

Tags: php, hash, base-conversion

Is there a way to take any number, from say, 1 to 40000 and generate an 8 character hash?

I was thinking of using `base_convert` but couldn't figure out a way to force it to be an 8 character hash.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: With `base_convert`, you could go down to a maximum of 3 characters (!) for your range of numbers. If you always need 8, you probably want [`(new Id())->encode($id)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-IDs). You may have to prepend leading zeros (or other characters), but even substrings of MD5 can have leading zeros (though with lower probability).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Why don't you just run `md5` and take the first 8 characters?

Because you are wanting a hash, it doesn't matter whether portions are discarded, but rather that the same input will produce the same hash.

```
$hash = substr(md5($num), 0, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks to whoever fixed that. I must be asleep.

Comment: Is there any chance of a collision in my number range?

Comment: Better instinct tells me no... but you might want to run a test. Since 40,000 is not a huge number, you could easily test that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing this now with a random hash associated with a session.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> math.exp(math.log(40000)/8)
3.7606030930863934
```

Therefore you need 4 digit-symbols to produce a 8-character hash from 40000:

```
sprintf("%08s", base_convert($n, 10, 4))
```

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 8.1 you can use [xxHash](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/xxHash) to get 8 characters hash of any string or number variable.

```php
$number = random_int(1, 40_000);
$hash = hash('xxh32', (string) $number);

var_dump($hash); // Output is string(8) "af863d37"
```

Answer (score 1):

For php:

```
$seed = 'JvKnrQWPsThuJteNQAuH';
$hash = sha1(uniqid($seed . mt_rand(), true));

# To get a shorter version of the hash, just use substr
$hash = substr($hash, 0, 10);
```

http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=20236

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways ...

one example

```
$x = ?
$s = '';
for ($i=0;$i<8;++$i)
{
    $s .= chr( $x%26 + ord('a') );
    $x /= 26;
}
```

Comment: isn't this just effectively changing the base of the number?

Comment: sure.  but the request was pretty vague - it just asked for an 8char hash.

Comment: Sorry about how vaguely I asked the question :( I'm trying to generate an 8 character hash from any integer but don't just want to pad the remaining length of the hash with something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$hash = substr(hash("sha256",$num), 0, 8);
```

Comment: How does this differ from mine? `md5` is pretty strong. Why `sha256`?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: md5 is pretty weak. It just takes hours to create collisions.

Comment: Hey, this can clear u which one is best [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948156/algorithm-complexity-security-md5-or-sha1)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to convert a 6 digit number into a 8 digit string reproducibly?

```
sprintf("%08d", $number);
```

Certainly a hash is not reversible - but without a salt / IV it might be a bit easy to hack. A better solution might be:

```
substr(sha1($number . $some_secret),0,8);
```

C.