# SHA checksum for +2GB file using FileStream

Tags: c#, .net, sha

Why in this soulution which I found there is no Loop to use buffor few times?

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

private static string GetChecksum(string file)
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(file))
    {
        SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to generate SHA checksum for +2GB file. How it should be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a file SHA256 Hash code and Checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474362/get-a-file-sha256-hash-code-and-checksum)

Comment: @Sinatr Example code here, is from there :)

Comment: @AramKocharyan, the questions (as it seems to me) are too. I hope OP will clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: ComputeHash() slurps the entire stream by itself.  Convenient.  That buffer is [still there](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hashalgorithm.cs,57).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why in this soulution which I found there is no Loop to use buffor few times?

Because `ComputeHash` takes care of reading the entire stream and computing the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netframework-4.7) override.

The loop is under the hood.

Here is simplified source code of `ComputeHash` method:

```
public byte[] ComputeHash(Stream inputStream) 
{
    ...
    // Default the buffer size to 4K.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; 
    int bytesRead;
    do { 
        bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096); 
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            HashCore(buffer, 0, bytesRead);  // Actual hashing
        }
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
    ...
}
```

As you can see `ComputeHash` is actually hashing by **4096 byte** chunks.

Comment: And it is extremely slow on large files. So, unfortunately, everyone who cares about performance have to re-implement chunking logic using larger buffer.

Comment: How large should the buffers be?