# What is the most efficient way to generate 8 character random alphanumeric string in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to generate a unique 8 character random alphanumeric string in TSQL, for a mail confirm link. We are currently using a **GUID** but it is not very user friendly.

It only really has to obey a few rules:

- be 8 Characters long
- be unique
- be generated efficiently

Comment: Does `LEFT(NEWID(),8)` not do what you need? (In conjunction with a unique constraint)

Comment: Similar question:
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520794/php-generate-an-8-character-hash-from-an-integer

Comment: @MartinSmith I was thinking the same, but those will very often be the same numbers and they are not that randomized

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are 2 ways of solving it

Method 1: This will generate 8 random characters and store them in varchar @r, in order to prevent all the individual characters from being identical, I added a seed to RAND().

```
DECLARE @r varchar(8)

SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') +CHAR(
CASE WHEN r between 0 and 9 THEN 48
WHEN r between 10 and 35 THEN 55
ELSE 61 END + r)
FROM
master..spt_values
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT CAST(RAND(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) *61 as int) r) a
WHERE type = 'P' AND number < 8
```

Method 2: This method is using a tally table, each character will never occur more than once. The rows used to generate these characters are randomized by ordering on newid()

```
DECLARE @r varchar(8)

SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') + n
FROM (SELECT top 8 
CHAR(number) n FROM
master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P' AND 
(number between ascii(0) and ascii(9)
or number between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
or number between ascii('a') and ascii('z'))
ORDER BY newid()) a
```

In order to ensure uniqueness for each varchar(8) you can store the results in a table and compare with result in that table. You can also make the varchar longer and just hope for the best

Comment: If you're using method 1 for generating large amounts of data, be careful.  The line `RAND(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` will fall over once every 4 billion times it's called.  The issue is that when CHECKSUM produces the largest possible negative int (-2147483648) and that value is fed into the ABS function.  The largest possible positive int is 2147483647.  This results in an arithmetic overflow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: My solution was this expression `RAND(Utilities.CapForRand(ABS(CAST(BINARY_CHECKSUM(NEWID()) as bigint)))`  Casting the result of the BINARY_CHECKSUM to a bigint gets around the arithmetic overflow in ABS as the bigint will hold 2147483648 and ABS goes into bigint mode when passed a bigint.  However RAND requires an int so I wrote a utility function that takes a bigint, if it's larger than the largest possible positive int then it returns the largest possible positive int, otherwise it returns the passed in value as an int.

Comment: @GilesRoberts, would you mind reviewing http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0d24a/2 and tell me if it's right or not. Cheers!

Answer (score 36):

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()), 0, 7)
```

Comment: You had an extra parenthesis but I removed it. Thanks for sharing +1

Comment: Due to the way that [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) works, `0,7` will actually produce **6** not **8** characters.  Using `1,8` will give you the required 8

Comment: this will convert 8 hex numbers to a varchar. It will eliminate the rest of the alphabet

Comment: How do you guarantee the uniqueness ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`CHAR(ROUND(RAND() * 93 + 33, 0))` to generate a random character.

Then look to see if that is one of the characters you may disallow, such as single quotes, perhaps, then build up your string, doing all of this in a loop.

Comment: You are almost sure of getting characters that are not alphanumeric with that script, if you use it in my first example you get 8 identical characters.