# Generate unique random IDs looping through SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, random, uniqueidentifier

This question is related to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934330/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-generate-8-character-random-alphanumeric-strin), not sure if I am supposed to post this new question in that post or create a new post, but was worried it might not get seen as a follow up question within the old post ...

- I need to replace a bunch of IDs with random but unique new ones in an SQL table.
- I am using t-clausen.dk's code snip from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934330/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-generate-8-character-random-alphanumeric-strin) to generate the new IDs.
- I am using a temp table to iterate through the old IDs, generating the new ID, and then updating my table with the new ID. (that part of the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662356/sql-server-loop-how-do-i-loop-through-a-set-of-records))
- **My problem is that all of the new IDs end up being the same. How can I get @r to clear out so that it can generate a new number?**
- **Or is there a better way to solve this issue generally? Say without looping ...?**

  ```
  SELECT * INTO #ControlTable FROM tempmaster 
  DECLARE @ei varchar(max)
  DECLARE @r  varchar(8)

  WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #ControlTable)
  BEGIN
      SELECT @ei = (SELECT TOP 1 externalid FROM #ControlTable ORDER BY externalid ASC)

      -- CREATE UNIQUE RANDOM ID
      SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') + n
      FROM (SELECT top 8 
      CHAR(number) n FROM
      master..spt_values
      WHERE type = 'P' AND 
      (number between ascii(0) and ascii(9)
      or number between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
      or number between ascii('a') and ascii('z'))
      ORDER BY newid()) a

      -- REPLACE OLD ID
      UPDATE tempmaster SET externalid  = @r WHERE externalid = @ei

      DELETE #ControlTable WHERE externalid = @ei

      /*TESTING*/
      --SELECT @ei AS EI, @r AS [newID]
      --SELECT * FROM #ControlTable
      --SELECT * FROM tempmaster WHERE externalid = @ei OR externalid = @r
  END

  drop table #ControlTable
  ```

HERE IS AN OUTLINE OF AN ATTEMPT AT A SET-BASED APPROACH

```
    DECLARE @r varchar(8);
    SELECT oid, startdate, enddate,
        coalesce(@r, '') + n
        FROM (SELECT TOP 8 
        CHAR(number) n FROM
        master..spt_values
        WHERE type = 'P' AND 
        (number between ascii(0) and ascii(9)
        or number between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
        or number between ascii('a') and ascii('z'))
        ORDER BY newid()) 
    as externalid
    FROM MasterTable
```

Comment: Is your original externalid already unique?

Comment: yes the original id is a unique varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this, but you could replace the loop by this `UPDATE` statement. It requires your current *enternalid* values to be unique:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        externalid,
        concat(
            substring(chars, num % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/62) % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/3844) % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/238328) % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/14776336) % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/916132832) % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/56800235584) % 62, 1),
            substring(chars, (num/3521614606208) % 62, 1)
        ) AS unique_string8 
    FROM (
        SELECT
            externalid,
            (rn * 34524689549219 + seed) % 199689672115897 AS num,
            '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' AS chars
        FROM (
            SELECT externalid,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY externalid) AS rn,
                   0 AS seed
            FROM   tempmaster
        ) AS subq1
    ) AS subq2
)
UPDATE     t
SET        externalid = cte.unique_string8
FROM       tempmaster t
INNER JOIN cte
        ON cte.externalid = t.externalid;
```

The idea is that the *cte* query maps your existing *externalid* with the new 8-character key, and then performs the update using that mapping.

The characters are taken from a literal string with the 62 possible characters. The value *num* is a multiple of a prime plus some seed (0 in this case) and kept within in limits by taking the modulo by a prime that is close to the number of possible strings with 8 characters.

This resulting number is then translated into an 8 character string as if the number is to represented in 62-base. The denominators in the formula are powers of 62.

This way, it is guaranteed that you'll never get a duplicate (unless you have more records than possible 8-letter combinations).

There is no random part, so it will produce always the same series, but you can change the *seed* value to any integer number to change the series that will be produced.

Answer (score 2):

Although your loop is not how I would approach the problem (a set-based approach is much better), your problem is that you do not re-initialize `@r` inside the loop.

So, add:

```
set @r = NULL;
```

to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: doh, thank you. how would the set-based approach work? will post edit in original post showing what i tried

Comment: @dharol . . . Can you ask another question?  The answer is quite different from this question.