# How to generate hash from timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I must generate unique hash - maybe from timestamp. hash must have max 8 chars. How to do it?

For now I have only timestamp:

```
var t = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: You'll have to use some library to generate hash. You can try this:
https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Comment: [Related: Generate an 8 character hash from an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520794/php-generate-an-8-character-hash-from-an-integer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That may look funny but the following code may work well for the next couple of centuries `:)`

```
(+new Date).toString(36);  // "iepii89m"
```

After that you can extend it with slicing method: `(+new Date).toString(36).slice(-8)`.

Comment: And if you wish to minimize the possibility of collision you can try this: `((+new Date) + Math.random()* 100).toString(32)`

Comment: @DanielSokolowski Why would it help in minimising the possibility of collision? I'd argue that it's exactly the opposite.

Comment: can you explain what is that + for, very curious

Comment: @Bardia This is basically a shortcut for `Number(new Date).toString(36)`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus.

Comment: Date.now().toString(36)
i think this is prettier

Comment: Great answer here! There's a lot of scenarios where you don't really need UUID but need a unique string based off the progression of time.